# SQL set increasing integer where value of column is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set which looks like:

```
Id INT,
Choice VARCHAR,
Order INT
```

`Id` + `Choice` form the primary key.

Currently a lot of the rows have `Order` = 1.

What I would like to do is, for each `Id`, if there are multiple rows with that `Id` where `Order = 1`, set them to be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I can't work out the SQL to do this.

Example data:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| Id | Choice | Order |
+----+--------+-------+
|  4 | hello  |     1 |
|  4 | world  |     1 |
|  4 | test   |     1 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Would become:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| Id | Choice | Order |
+----+--------+-------+
|  4 | hello  |     1 |
|  4 | world  |     2 |
|  4 | test   |     3 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is the logic behind the ordering?  Can `Order` ever have a value _other_ than 1?

Comment: Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You will want to use the optional PARTITION

Comment: Don't you just want to make the order id an identity column?

Comment: @user1443098 no. They want this to restart for each new value of Id.

Comment: OIC. Well, I'd split the items into an order item table, with an identity column and a FK ref to the order table.  But then, I wouldn't be concerned that all order items begin at number 1.  Only sure-fire way to do this with the current design for future rows (not just fix the current ones) is with a trigger to compute the item numbers.  You could put that in the  business logic if you like,  though I like the "set it and forget it" aspect of a trigger.

Answer (score 4):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here with a partition by `Id`.  As for the ordering in your `Order` column, I don't see any logic present for how you numbered things.  In the absence of this, I use the `Choice` column to decide how to order the row numbering.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Choice) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE [Order] = 1
)

UPDATE cte
SET [Order] = rn;
```

Note: Please *avoid* naming your columns (tables, etc.) using reserved SQL keywords like `ORDER`.  You will forever have to put that column name in square brackets, like this: `[Order]`.